Add an image in prompt for AzureOpenAI gpt4-mini?
I am able to use the web interface of azure OpenAI studio in the chat playground to analyze images but I would like to do the same using python. It seems that it's not working and I could not (so far) find a reference online on how to include an image in the prompt. Could anyone please help or provide a reference on how I can do this? Do I actually need to upload my image or would it be possible for the model to read a local image. ?
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    api_version=os.getenv("AZURE_API_VERSION"),
    azure_endpoint=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"),
)

deployment_name = "gpt-4o-mini"  
# Send a completion call to generate an answer
print("Sending a test completion job")
#image local path
image_input = r"c:/users/..../image.jpeg"
prompt = "Tell me what do you see in this image ![image]({{image_input}}) "

messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    messages=messages,
    temperature=0,
)
generated_text = response.choices[0].message.content
print("Response:", generated_text)

Update:
I uploaded also the image to the blob storage and I replaced the local path with the URL, I still get the same response from the model:
Response: It seems that I can't view images directly. However, if you describe the image or provide details about its content, I can help analyze it or provide insights based on your description!


it seems like API is not allowed to view images. There is no solution for that, Engineers designed it this way, However maybe you can try embed bitmap inside of prompt and see what happens next.

can you check this documentation here if this meet your expectation
